# BigQuery to GCS and GCS to Mysql

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am creating a Airflow pipeline where I use the `BigQueryOperator` to query my BigQuery tables and use the `BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator` to export the result table to GCS as csv.

I need to move the csv to a mysql database where it should be stored as a table in the mysql database.

Can I please get any advice or ideas on how to implement this. Thanks!

Comment: Cloud SQL can load CSV file. If no operator exist, you can create a python operator and call the API for this. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Since your use case is query data in BigQuery and store data in your MySql database you can use [BigQueryToMySqlOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_mysql/index.html?highlight=bigquery#module-airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.bigquery_to_mysql).

> Fetches the data from a BigQuery table (alternatively fetch data for
> selected columns) and insert that data into a MySQL table.